# Function that takes any collection as argument Scala

Tags: scala

I've been trying to write a function, that takes any collection that inherits Seq trait and performs action on it. I've come up with this:

```
def printAll[A, B <: Seq[A]] (xs: B) = {
  xs foreach println
}
```

But this function works only with such arguments:

```
printAll(Seq.empty)
printAll(List())
```

etc. How can I improve it to work in this way for example:

```
printAll(List(1,2,3)) // scala> 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your goal is to take any collection that inherits (or is viewable as) a Seq, you can just do that:

```
  def printAll[A](xs: Seq[A]) = {
     xs foreach println
  }
```

using your version you have to give the type inferencer a hint:

```
printAll[Int, List[Int]](List(1, 2, 3))
```